# Derivation of Pearson's Product Moment Correlation Coefficient's (PPMCC) distribution from bivariate normal variables?

Tags: distributions, correlation, random-variable, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm interested in reading through the derivation of the probability density function that PPMCC follows when it's input is a bivariate normal variables. [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficientBivariateNormalDistribution.html) gives the following equalities:

$$P(r) = \frac{1}{\pi}(N-2)(1-r^2)^{\frac{N-4}{2}}(1-\rho^2)^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{d \beta}{(\cosh \beta - \rho r)^{N-1}}$$

$$P(r) = \frac{1}{\pi}(N-2)(1-r^2)^{\frac{N-4}{2}}(1-\rho^2)^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\Gamma(N-1)}{\Gamma(N-\frac{1}{2})} (1-\rho r)^{-\frac{N-3}{2}} {_2}F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2N-1}{2}, \frac{\rho r + 1}{2} \right)$$

$$P(r) = \frac{(N-2)\Gamma(N-1)(1-\rho^2)^{\frac{N-1}{2}}(1-r^2)^{\frac{N-4}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\Gamma(N-\frac{1}{2})(1-\rho r)^{\frac{N-3}{2}}} \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\rho r + 1}{2N-1} + \frac{9}{16} \frac{(\rho r + 1)^2}{(2N-1)(2N+1)} + \cdots\right]$$

Mathworld inline cites **Kenney and Keeping 1951, pp. 217-221** which is given in the references as **Kenney, J. F. and Keeping, E. S. Mathematics of Statistics, Pt. 2, 2nd ed. Princeton, NJ: Van Nostrand, 1951.** Unfortunately I seem to be unable to access this document at this time.

I've wondered if the derivation might involve something similar to a "[ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution)-of-[products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) distribution" because the correlation coefficient can be defined as the following:

$$\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2}}$$

What are the complete steps of the derivation of

$$P(r) = \frac{1}{\pi}(N-2)(1-r^2)^{\frac{N-4}{2}}(1-\rho^2)^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{d \beta}{(\cosh \beta - \rho r)^{N-1}}$$

from knowing (any required theorems or axioms and) the equation of the correlation coefficient and the density functions of the original variables?